# Django: Stacking decorators

Tags: python, django

I have the following signal. Is it possible to 'stack' these two decorators as I did here?

```
@receiver(signal=charge_succeeded)
@transaction.atomic
def create_influencer_transaction(sender, order, charge, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Comment: Should work - did you encounter any problems or errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Considering how decorators work, this is equivalent to

```py
def create_influencer_transaction(sender, order, charge, **kwargs):
    pass


create_influencer_transaction = transaction.atomic(
    create_influencer_transaction
)
create_influencer_transaction = receiver(signal=charge_succeeded)(
    create_influencer_transaction
)
```

– `transaction.atomic` will return a new function that has the atomicity wrapper logic, but `receiver` will just return the same function.

However, order here does matter (and you've got it right); if the decorators were the other way around, `receiver` would register the non-atomic version, which is not good.